# Create shortcut in Dymola to perform action

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, modelica, dymola

i would like to create shortcut (keyboard) to perform some action in Dymola.
For example i would like to push a key (or keys combinaison ) to simulate the current model or to simulate a determined open model.

The second possibility would be perfect because when we work on a submodel it is required to open the main model before the simulating.

Moreover, the keybord shorcuts are very poor in Dymola and i would like to improve the user interface

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a Hotkey, one solution is to use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/).  That way, you don't need to actually change Dymola in any way.